# angularjs ng-options with angular-ui-select

Tags: angularjs, ng-options

Argh, this again.
I have a list of objects:

```
var roles = [{
    id: 1,
    name: 'Administrator'
}];
```

I am using ng-options and I want to display the name and when selected, it should use the name, but there is a filter. I tried this:

```
role.name for role in (roleController.roles | filter: $select.search) track by role.id
```

But it is throwing an error.
Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: Can you post the error that it is giving?

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
role.id as role.name for role in  (roleController.roles | filter: $select.search) track by role.id
```

Comment: Please add some explanation of why this code helps the OP. This will help provide an answer future viewers can learn from. See [answer] for more information.